# Not submitting images in a form in django

Tags: python, django, deployment, backend

It is even more accurate to say that the image name is sent, but nothing changes. I have a user model. The user has his own avatar (ImageField). I have written a form and put everything in the template. When submitting the form, everything is saved except the image. But when changing in the admin everything is fine. Why? Help me please already tried everything does not help!!!!

settings.py:

```
`MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"`
```

models.py:

```
class Women(models.Model):
    class Status(models.IntegerChoices):
        DRAFT = 0, 'Черновик'
        PUBLISHED = 1, 'Опубликовано'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Заголовок")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="Slug",                           validators=[
                               MinLengthValidator(5, message="Минимум 5 символов"),
                               MaxLengthValidator(100, message="Максимум 100 символов"),
                           ])
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",default=None,blank=True,null=True,verbose_name="Фото")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Текст статьи")
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Время создания")
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Время изменения")
    is_published = models.BooleanField(choices=tuple(map(lambda x: (bool(x[0]), x[1]), Status.choices)),
                                       default=Status.DRAFT, verbose_name="Статус")
    cat = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='posts', verbose_name="Категории")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('TagPost', blank=True, related_name='tags', verbose_name="Теги")
    husband = models.OneToOneField('Husband', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                   null=True, blank=True, related_name='wuman', verbose_name="Муж")

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Известные женщины"
        verbose_name_plural = "Известные женщины"
        ordering = ['-time_create']
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['-time_create'])
        ]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
```

forms.py:

```
class AddPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cat = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), empty_label="Категория не выбрана", label="Категории")
    husband = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Husband.objects.all(), empty_label="Не замужем", required=False, label="Муж")

    class Meta:
        model = Women
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'content', 'photo','is_published', 'cat', 'husband', 'tags']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 5}),
        }
        labels = {'slug': 'URL'}

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if len(title) > 50:
            raise ValidationError("Длина превышает 50 символов")

        return title
```

views.py:

```
def addpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
       
            form.save()
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        form = AddPostForm()

    data = {
        'menu': menu,
        'title': 'Добавление статьи',
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'women/addpage.html', data)
```

html:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-error">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
    {% for f in form %}
    <p><label class="form-label" for="{{ f.id_for_label }}">{{ f.label }}</label>{{ f }}</p>
    <div class="form-error">{{ f.errors }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><button type="submit">Отправить</button></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I don`t know what to do

Comment: Try `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` as `MEDIA_ROOT`

`import os` if not already there.

Comment: I have just tried it didn`t help

Comment: Provide your urls.py file codes as well

Comment: it`s in my app 
**




urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),  # http://127.0.0.1:8000
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('addpage/', views.addpage, name='add_page'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('post/<slug:post_slug>/', views.show_post, name='post'),
    path('category/<slug:cat_slug>/', views.show_category, name='category'),
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.show_tag_postlist, name='tag'),
]
**

Comment: it`s in my main program
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('women.urls')),
    path("__debug__/", include("debug_toolbar.urls")),
]

Comment: Got it. I have write a answer and explain check that and this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` as MEDIA_ROOT in your `settings.py`

`import os` if not already there.

In your app `urls.py` you have not include the serving of media files.
Add this at the end of your `urls.py` file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('addpage/', views.addpage, name='add_page'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('post/<slug:post_slug>/', views.show_post, name='post'),
    path('category/<slug:cat_slug>/', views.show_category, name='category'),
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.show_tag_postlist, name='tag'),
]


urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) #make sure MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings.py
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: from where i should import static

Comment: I have added that check

Comment: I add this ,but it still doesn`t work

Comment: do you have any ideas what to do?

Comment: What is the value set as MEDIA_URL in your settings.py?